UI freezes after showing toast after handling illegal exception in main Application
I was trying to implement a centralized error capturing and showing the user a Toast message (app was crashing). I have since moved on and just doing try catch for each case but I couldn't figure out why the UI freezes after showing Toast correctly.
this is the code:
   Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { thread, throwable ->
    if (throwable is IllegalArgumentException) {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                throwable.message ?: "error found",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            ).show()
        }
        // Don't terminate the app
        
        return@setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler
    }

    Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()?.uncaughtException(thread, throwable)
}

the error is triggered by a require() statement after a click of a button and correctly shown but after that, the UI completely freezes and I couldn't figure out at all why.
